# Create and dynamically modify .dtsx file via MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ssis

I am attempting to utilize a single .dtsx file with a dynamic execution file name through MS Access VBA. I am attempting to do this as part of an Access tool already created at work. While I

I have been able to get around the issue of linking the .dtsx to multiple files in the same folder by renaming each file to a singular, unique name, running the .dtsx, and then changing the name back. However, the folder directory is not necessarily guaranteed, as many other users may use the tool.

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime  

Module ApplicationTests  

  Sub Main()  

    ' The variable pkg points to the location of the  
    ' ExecuteProcess package sample that was installed with  
    ' the SSIS samples.  
    Dim pkg As String = _  
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Samples\Integration Services" & _  
      "\Package Samples\ExecuteProcess Sample\ExecuteProcess\UsingExecuteProcess.dtsx"  

    Dim app As Application = New Application()  
    Dim p As Package = app.LoadPackage(pkg, Nothing)  

    ' Now that the package is loaded, we can query on  
    ' its properties.  
    Dim n As Integer = p.Configurations.Count  
    Dim p2 As DtsProperty = p.Properties("VersionGUID")  
    Dim pl As DTSProtectionLevel = p.ProtectionLevel  

    Console.WriteLine("Number of configurations = " & n.ToString())  
    Console.WriteLine("VersionGUID = " & CType(p2.GetValue(p), String))  
    Console.WriteLine("ProtectionLevel = " & pl.ToString())  
    Console.Read()  

  End Sub  

End Module
```

This is the code I found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/creating-a-package-programmatically?view=sql-server-ver15, but it only works for VB.Net, which I do not have access to. I am hoping to mimic this idea, but in Access VBA - create/modify a SSIS package.

Comment: If you navigate to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` do you see csc.exe in one of those folders (i.e. v2.0.50727, v4.0.30319)?

Comment: Also, does your above code actually *work* or is representative of what you hope to accomplish with vbscript/vba?

Comment: I do not have the csc.exe file.

Comment: I assume the code works, but I am not able to test it on my device. However, it touches on the modification of a SSIS package, from which I hope to create something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my quick searching confirmed what I believed to be true - VBA/VBScript isn't going to work with the object model that you are attempting to pull in with your `Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime`

You can write a bridge between the DTS assemblies so that you can use it in VBA but given that you're attempting to use Access's VBA because you don't have access to proper tooling, well, there's a circular reference.

### Alternatives.

SQL Server Data Tools, SSDT, is free. It is the tool for authoring SSIS packages. It has a Script Task that uses .NET and has the references to the managed object model already set so write a package that modifies another package.

Expressions - most every object within an SSIS package supports Expressions so with sufficient elbow grease, you can get some very dynamic packages up and running.

Biml - Business Intelligence Markup Language is a free addon for Visual Studio that takes a different approach to making packages.

A common data processing pattern is a truncate and reload of data. Many neophytes to SSIS want a single package that takes any source and matches it to a destination and they want that to be dynamic - specify a new source/destination and magic happens. The engine doesn't support that. What Biml let's you do is define the pattern - Truncate a table -> Data flow with flat file source to OLE DB Destination. Now that you've got your pattern, you then use metadata (these files go to these target tables) and build out N packages. You get an explosion of packages but you don't care because the hard part was defining the pattern and collecting the metadata. The packages are almost disposable artifacts as they'll be standard across the entire ecosystem you develop.